# Unable to change the height using ang-jsoneditor for Json editor with Angular 6

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

We are using [ang-jsoneditor](https://github.com/mariohmol/ang-jsoneditor) **NPM** Module for adding the **JSON** editor in my **Angular 6** application. This JSON editor is working fine in call cases except this one, I am trying to change the **height** of my **JSON editor** when I am opening it in **Code** mode. 
Can anybody help me to find out the solution for this please ?

Following is my code in .ts file :

```
import { JsonEditorOptions, JsonEditorComponent } from 'ang-jsoneditor';

public editorOptions: JsonEditorOptions;
  @ViewChild(JsonEditorComponent) editor: JsonEditorComponent;

  constructor(private dataModelService: DataModelService) {
    this.editorOptions = new JsonEditorOptions();
   }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.editorOptions.mode = this.jsonEditorMode ? this.jsonEditorMode : 'code';
     // Following Code is not working for height
    // this.editor.setOptions({
    //   maxLines: Infinity});
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add below css in style.scss of your app

```
div.jsoneditor-mode-code{
  height:500px; //100vh if you want full screen
  }
```